# Making a probability into rate of change?

Tags: probability

If I have a counter that every time interval $t$ seconds (e.g every 10 seconds) has a constant probability of 5.9% to increase the counter by 1. What would be the expected rate of change of the counter per second ($\Delta n=\frac{n}{t}$, *where $n=$ the value of the counter*)?

Would the $\Delta n$ just be the probability over time
$\Delta n= \frac{P(change)}{t}$?

Comment: First 10 seconds:

$P(change) = \frac{5.9}{100}$   

2nd 10 seconds:  

$P(change) = \frac{5.9}{100}$

You used the word "constant". Why would you ask for rate of *change*?

Comment: I used constant to describe the fact that the probability does not change as time passes, would uniform be better to describe the probability, or should I re-word the question?

Comment: We start off from 0. $E(X) = 0.059 \times 1 + 0.941 \times 0 = 0.059$.  That is to say, the counter's rate of change is 0.059 per 10 seconds. So in a 100 seconds, the counter should read approximately 5.9. Does this seem reasonable?